# A solution to deal with disconnects / afks in MOBAs?

Tags: league-of-legends, smite, moba

I wonder, why there isn't a system to deal with afk/dc in MOBAs (or any other team-based game mode), most arguments are like:

- the smaller team gets more exp/gold since it's divided to a smaller group
  (But this wouldn't concern late game, when everybody is already full equipped/level)
- with good communication you can win a 4v5
  (But this also work the other way, you can easily win a 5vs4 with good communication)

Often player wants some kind of buffs, to compensate the missing player, like:

- increased income (gold)
- increased stats
- Bot take position of missing player
- (Or my favorite) another random player in queue can replace the dc'ed player (But the originally can't rejoin)

But 1 and 2 can be abused by leaving a game on purpose and join the game later.

Since I only have this experience from LoL and Smite, have any other games a solution for this problem?

Comment: i suggest NOT to post this in a official LoL forum ;) you will be flamed like never before in your life...

Answer (score 2):

In DotA (the Warcraft III map) you can't rejoin the game and:

- The AFK Champ can be controlled by anybody (kind of useless).
- The Items can be sold and the amount is divided under all other players from the same team
- You can drop and pick up the items with your own champ.

> **why** there isn't a system to deal with afk/dc in MOBAs

stupid answer, but: the designers/developers have chosen not to do this. In most games there is a system: If you DC too often you will be banned.

### Reasons against your suggestions:

- A bot might be worse than an AFK standing in base (feeding)
- A random player has to play THAT champion, with THAT build, which would definitly suck.

### League of Legends

- Leavers get reported automatically
- Your MMR is adjusted if there are leavers in the game.

### Just deal with leavers!

It might seem, that YOUR team always has the leavers, but thats not the case!

The chances are 5:4 that the enemy has a leaver.

### Ragequitters

If you flame a lot, it might be that you force your teammates to leave ("omg, jinx you noob! plz unistall"). If that's the case, you have to work on that. or maybe you are the ragequitter...

Comment: A side note: The original *DotA* didn't allow rejoining as a technical limitation of *Warcraft III*.

Answer (score 0):

I've won a few 4v5 but it's certain rare.

The big problem with your "random player joins" suggestion is that they don't get to choose the champion, do the runes and masteries change? What about the items? Do they get to sell and rebuy all the items or put up with whatever the afker built? Do they still get penalties for losing? Points for winning?

How does the matchmaker determine the right person to join?

Lets say I join a game at 40 minutes, take over a weak horribly underfarmed champion just as the enemy team rush the base and take the nexus. Do I lose LP? What about if I join just as the team wins, do I gain LP?

How does the system work out how much LP I should gain or lose? If I never lose LP then it's a guaranteed way to level up just joining these games. If I do lose LP then I'm taking a big gamble that when I join the situation isn't completely lost already.

Answer (score 0):

No moba has a solution for this simply because it's impossible to solve this problem without breaking the game. If you give a boost or bonus to a team that has 1 player less it could be abused by both teams. Some of these solutions and why they don't work:

- Boosting Stats - Some champions/heroes scale different than others
- No / Fewer Ranking loss - You could force someone to leave
- Someone joins the match - You couldn't chose what character you play and often players leave when they're about to lose (which kinda sucks for the player who just joined)
- Bot takes position - Bots are pretty much free food for an more or less experienced player

Some mobas try to get a solution:

**Dota 2**
Players can control the AFK Hero and you can safely leave after some time. Again the thing with controlling the Hero is kind of useless because it's still one player less since you can't control 2 Characters at the same time and the leaving without penalties can be abused.

**League of Legends**
Players get reported automatically and if you leave too often a special matchmaking gets triggered that places you in queue with other players with negative behavior to prevent the non-toxic or positive players from playing with you. Here the problem is that if you have a bad connection you will get placed with toxic people although you didn't even do something bad on purpose.

Basically the only thing you can really do is trying to be patient. Leavers are really annoying and frustrating but it's completely impossible to create a system against them without breaking the game.

Comment: In regards to Dota 2, yes it's very possible to control and equip 2 characters at once. It's so possible that a hero exists which is based on exactly this mechanic (Lone Druid). -- Also, when the person is AFK or disconnected for 5 minutes, the game is "safe to leave" and any *previous* leavers get marked, and after some infractions go to the "low priority queue", which similarly to LoL, only allows matches with other penalized players (exception is when a non-low-priority player joins a queue in party with a low-priority player: both will play the LP game).